# CF7 with JavaScript Disabled – After form submit, refreshing page resubmits form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I prefer to do all the styling and JavaScript functionality myself, so in wp-config.php I’ve set the following:

```
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, false );
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_CSS’, false );
```

On submit everything is fine. It reloads the page and shows the success message. The problem is if I refresh the page again it resubmits the form. There is no post data that gets resubmitted, so CF7 must be using the form submission hash that gets added onto the URL. Shouldn't it recognize this hash exists already and not submit the form again?

I can’t find anything on Google about this. Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? Just hit the same wall... :/

Comment: @Beaniie It's been a long time but I think I just redirected to another URL with JavaScript. Whatever I ended up doing it was not ideal :/

Comment: I see, well I'll keep searching for the time being seeing what I can turn up. If not i'll have to do the same. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

you have to redirect the page to thank you page after mail sent using contact form 7 hook

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    global $post;
   wp_redirect(site_url('thank-you');
   exit;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m confused though why this is necessary, because it shows the “success” messages after the form page reloads. So it seems like users are supposed to see the refreshed page.

Comment: @gavin if you dont want the user to thank you page then redirect to the same page where your contact form is exist.